# C++ How to handle a change of pointers and references in a function?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

```
void parameterMystery3(int* a, int& b, int* c) {
    *a += *c;
    (*c)++;
    b--;
    cout << b << " " << *a << " " << *c << end1;
}

int main() {
    int w = -4;
    int x = 10;
    int y = 9;
    int z = 13;

    parameterMystery3(&x, x, &w);
}
```

If argument 2 (at the end of main()) passes x as a normal variable (not a pointer or a reference), does it only reference x in parameterMystery3? Do the &s at the end of main matter if they get converted to pointers with int* a and int* b or am I thinking about it incorrectly?

Comment: I'm sure that the expected behavior of this gets explicitly specified somewhere. But, personally, I prefer the "Doctor, it hurts when I move my arm this way. -- well, don't move your arm that way, then" approach. Life's too short...

Comment: `end1` should be `endl`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally find c++ reference notation a bit confusing.

The & in a parameter declaration means the argument is passed by reference. You pass x as argument. If you didn't declare the parameter as reference, a copy of x value would be passed. As you declared it as reference, a reference to x is passed. This means that, if you change b value, x value is changed.

Now, if you declare a parameter with a pointer type, a pointer of the declared type must be provided as argument. No conversion done. Passing an int variable as argument is a compile-time error. You must pass either an int* variable or a pointer to the variable.

You get a pointer to the variable with &.
The confusing thing is that this last & doesn't mean the same as the & in parameter b. While int &b means b is a reference to an int (the argument is passed by reference) the & before the variables you provide as arguments mean "a pointer to" the variable.

Therefore, if y is an int variable, &y is an int * pointing to y.

Comment: I didn't realize that the pointers and references also change the thing it references/points to originally. This makes sense now. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you modify a reference parameter, the value referenced by it is modified.

Comment: Sorry sent by mistake. If the parameter is a pointer type, then a pointer is passed by value.

Comment: If the parameter is int *a, and you have a variable x of type int *, a++ changes the place where a points to, but not the place where x points to. If you do (*a)++, then you are actually incrementing the value both a and x point to. Believe me, when you master C pointers, the secrets of the Universe will have no mistery for you ;)